# Kivy: Slider; How to set the position (value or normalized value on creation in declarations

Tags: kivy, slider

in the doccy the Slider position property is type AliasProperty.
I couldn't figure how to get the position set.
Anyone seen this work out there?
Strings, ints, and anything else I tried fell over.
Is there a special format to set/reference a slider position?
Thx

class MyContainer(GridLayout):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     
    # super function can be used to gain access to inherited methods from a parent or sibling class that has been overwritten in a class object.
    super(MyContainer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # 4 columns in grid layout
    self.cols = 4
     
    # declaring the slider and adding some effects to it self.brightnessControl = Slider(min = 0, max = 100)

    self.orientation = "lr-tb"
    self.changed = False

    self.brightnessControl = Slider(min = -255, max = 255, value_track = True, value_track_color =[1, 0, 0, 1])
    self.brightnessControl.id = 'brt slider'
    self.add_widget(Label(text ='brightness'))
    self.add_widget(self.brightnessControl)

    self.add_widget(Label(text ='Adj Brightness'))
    self.brightnessValue = Label(text = str(brightadj))
    self.add_widget(self.brightnessValue)
    # On the slider object Attach a callback for the attribute named value
    self.brightnessControl.bind(value = self.on_value)
         
    self.contrastControl = Slider(min = -255, max = 255, value_track = True, value_track_color =[1, 0, 0, 1])
    self.contrastControl.id = 'contr slider'
    self.add_widget(Label(text ='contrast'))
    self.add_widget(self.contrastControl)

    self.add_widget(Label(text ='Adj Contrast'))
    self.contrastValue = Label(text = str(contradj))
    self.add_widget(self.contrastValue)
    # On the slider object Attach a callback for the attribute named value
    self.contrastControl.bind(value = self.on_value)
    
    self.thresholdControl = Slider(min = 10, max = 245, value_track = True, value_track_color =[1, 0, 0, 1])
    self.thresholdControl.id = 'thresh slider'
    self.add_widget(Label(text ='threshold'))
    self.add_widget(self.thresholdControl)

    self.add_widget(Label(text ='Adj Threshold'))
    self.thresholdValue = Label(text = str(thresh))
    self.add_widget(self.thresholdValue)
    # On the slider object Attach a callback for the attribute named value
    self.thresholdControl.bind(value = self.on_value)

# Adding functionality behind the slider i.e when pressed increase the value
def on_value(self, instance, value):
    if instance.id == 'brt slider':
        self.brightnessValue.text = "% d"% value
        global brightadj
        brightadj = value

    if instance.id == 'contr slider':
        self.contrastValue.text = "% d"% value
        global contradj
        contradj = value

    if instance.id == 'thresh slider':
        self.thresholdValue.text = "% d"% value
        global thresh
        thresh = value

    MyContainer().changed = True
    MySliders.my_value(instance, value)
```

## The app class

class MySliders(App):

```
def build(self):
    myContainer = MyContainer()
    return myContainer

def my_value(self, value):
    print(int(value), self.id)
    MyContainer().changed = True
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `position` in the Slider, class, i assume you mean `value_pos` which is determined from the value, do you really need to change the `value_pos` independently of the value? If not, just set the appropriate value, and it’ll set the appropriate `value_pos`, if you do need to set it independently, you might want to build your own Slider like class, with the appropriate behavior for your use case, because Slider is not it.

Comment: value_pos is not determined from value, since on creation calue and value and value_pos don't match, the label value is changed explicitly operating the slider, but the first position doesnt match the instance value

Comment: WHat I did in the code above is to confuse Label.value with Slider.value.
THe Answer is:
set Numeric property value= in the slider declaration:
        self.contrastControl = Slider(min = -128, max = 128, value_track = True, 
                                                      value = contradj, value_track_color =[1, 0, 0, 1])

Comment: yes, that’s what i said, set the value, not the value_pos. Try to be clear on the name of the things you are asking about next time, the question was confusing and required guessing.